# PHP loop in for loop

Tags: php

I want to make `venue_` to running in loop together with the `venueName`. But seem it only display the last `venue_` result. Any idea what wrong with my code?

```js
$venueLength = 6;

for ($i = 0; $i < $venueLength; $i++) {
  $linkageArray = array();

  $mainArray = array ("venueName" => $venueArray[$i]['venueName']);

  for ($j = 0; $j < $venueLength; $j++) {
    $secondArray = array ( "venue_".$j => (in_array($venueArray[$j]['venueID'], $linkageArray) ? 'X' : ''));
  }

  $res[] = array_merge($mainArray, $secondArray); 
}   
header("Content-type: application/json");
$result = json_encode($res);
echo $result;
```

**Outcome**

```js
[
  {
    venueName: "Data A",
    venue_5: ""
  },
  {
    venueName: "Data A3",
    venue_5: ""
  },
  {
  ........
]
```

**Result I want**

```js
[
  {
    venueName: "Data A",
    venue_0: "",
    venue_1: "",
    venue_2: "",
    venue_3: "",
    venue_4: "",
    venue_5: ""
  },
  {
    venueName: "Data A3",
    venue_0: "",
    venue_1: "",
    venue_2: "",
    venue_3: "",
    venue_4: "",
    venue_5: ""
  },
  ........
]
```

Comment: `$secondArray = array...` overwriting `$secondArray` with every loop iteration. Last one wins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just keep on resetting the `$secondArray` value in

```
$secondArray = array ( "venue_".$j => (in_array($venueArray[$j]['venueID'], $linkageArray) ? 'X' : ''));
```

instead reset the array outside the loop and add a new value for each loop...

```
  $secondArray = [];
  for ($j = 0; $j < $venueLength; $j++) {
      $secondArray[ "venue_".$j ] = (in_array($venueArray[$j]['venueID'], $linkageArray) ? 'X' : ''));
  }
```

or just add it directly into `$mainArray`

```
  for ($j = 0; $j < $venueLength; $j++) {
      $mainArray[ "venue_".$j ] = (in_array($venueArray[$j]['venueID'], $linkageArray) ? 'X' : ''));
  }
```

and you don't need the `array_merge()`.

Comment: I try to add directly into $mainArray like you said but still not working? it get last `venueName` instead entire `venueName's` [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/deojwcq4/)

Comment: Do you add the data using `$res[] = $mainArray; `?